# What does it mean for two functions to be equivalent?

Tags: functions

What does it mean rigorously for two functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be equivalent? Does $f = g$ if and only if $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ \ f(x) = g(x)$?

Comment: There are a lot of different notions of equivalent for functions. The notion you've defined is equality, not equivalence.

Comment: In what context did you encounter this? The correct interpretation may be context-dependent.

Comment: If you give the same input *to* both, you get the same output *from* both. So, yes, they are equivalent from that perspective.

Comment: Re: Hold...  Jeez, guys! What could be more clear???

Comment: Sticklers may object to your usage of the equals sign in $f=g$. Maybe you should use $f\equiv g$.

Answer (score 5):

It means three things. First, the domains of the two functions must be the same. Secondly, the ranges (as apposed to images) of the functions must be the same.  Thirdly, for each element of the domain, the rule of the two functions must yield the same result.

Comment: I am discussing equality of functions.

Comment: Wouldn't the first and third statements imply the second? After all, if for all $x$, $f(x) = g(x)$, then it follows that every element of the range of $f$ is also in the range of $g$, and conversely.

Comment: @Strants I'm thinking ncmathsadist meant codomain instead of range.

Comment: I make a distinction.  There is the image of a function; this is $f(D)$, where $D$ is the domain of $f$.  The range of a function is the set you are specifying it takes values in.  If $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x) = x$ and $g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is defined by $g(x) = x$, I see these as different functions.